# Text and Chips together in one input of Angular Material

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, chips, angular-material-11

[image]

I want to have chips and text in one input. From what I could find there's always only chips. I have Angular v11 and [Angular Material v11](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/categories) in the project and the best way would be to use [Angular Chips](https://v11.material.angular.io/components/chips/examples)

Have you guys any kind of experience, samples, packages or advices how can I achieve this?

I tried to put texts between `<mat-chip>` components and it looks like what I want(image in the top), but you can't edit it and you can't treat it as a text because it's not inside the `<input>` element.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip>
      {{'Mike'}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <span> went on hike with </span>
    <mat-chip>
      {{'Jane'}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <span> and they met </span>
    <mat-chip>
      {{'Katie'}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <span> in the middle. </span>
    <input
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
    />
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcffu7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html)